# How to use nginx proxy with access token in url?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running nginx as a proxy for my backend services. I want to use url as `http://IP:PORT/<token>/endpoint` and which should be proxied to url as `http://backend/endpoint`

nginx.conf file:-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic safdadfWU6cdfdvcmQ=";
    }
}
```

Here I want to take `<token>` out of the url and pass remaining endpoint to my proxy_pass server. Kindly help me.

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ $1 break;` to remove the first path element from the URI.

Comment: Thank you for the response @RichardSmith, Could you tell me where should I put `rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ $1 break;` line in my nginx.conf file? Sorry, I'm naive with nginx proxy and config.

Comment: Inside the same location block as the proxy_pass statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Richard, Your suggestions helped in solving my Question. For other people's reference, the update nginx.conf file:-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        rewrite ^/[^/]+(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic safdadfWU6cdfdvcmQ=";
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to use url as `http://IP:PORT/<token>/endpoint` and which should be proxied to url as `http://backend/endpoint`

Comment: This seems to do nothing to validate that the token is any specific value. How could this be modified to asset that, for example, <token> is equal to `mySecret`?